# C UNIX datagram sockets -- how to get file descriptor into fd_set

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am using UNIX domain datagram sockets to send records from multiple clients to a single server in a multithreaded program.  Everything is done within one process; I'm sending records from multiple threads to a single thread that acts as the server.  All threads are assigned to separate cores using their affinity masks.

It works fine with a single client, but now I am using multiple clients.  The server will read data from the socket using select() to return file descriptors that are ready ("set"), then use recvfrom to get the records.

But first I need to write the file descriptors to the fd_set struct so I can use it with select().  I created fd_set as a global struct at the top of the C file that contains the programs to open client and server sockets and pass messages between them:

```
fd_set fdset;
```

I create client sockets in this way:

```
int64_t * create_socket_client(struct sockaddr_un claddr, int64_t retvals[])
{
    int sfd, j;
    size_t msgLen;
    ssize_t numBytes;
    char resp[BUF_SIZE];

    retvals[0] = 0;
    retvals[1] = 0;

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sfd == -1)
        return retvals;

    memset(&claddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    claddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    snprintf(claddr.sun_path, sizeof(claddr.sun_path),  "/tmp/ud_ucase_cl.%ld", (long) getpid());

    retvals[0] = sfd;
    retvals[1] = (int64_t)&claddr;

     return retvals;
}
```

The array retvals is passed in and returned with file descriptor and client address.  But to be used with select() I need to insert the file descriptor in the fd_set when the socket is created (in the program above).

Normally that wouldn't be a problem if I knew the layout of fd_set.  It's defined in sys/select.h:

```
/* fd_set for select and pselect.  */
typedef struct
  {
    /* XPG4.2 requires this member name.  Otherwise avoid the name
       from the global namespace.  */
#ifdef __USE_XOPEN
    __fd_mask fds_bits[__FD_SETSIZE / __NFDBITS];
# define __FDS_BITS(set) ((set)->fds_bits)
#else
    __fd_mask __fds_bits[__FD_SETSIZE / __NFDBITS];
# define __FDS_BITS(set) ((set)->__fds_bits)
#endif
  } fd_set;
```

but from that definition I can't tell what the fields are or how to get a file descriptor or array of file descriptors into fd_set.

So my question is:  how can I get the file descriptors into fd_set so it can be used with select()?

Comment: Tha man pages clearly explain how you do this. You have to use the `FD_SET` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to manipulate an `fd_set` is with the following macros (from the `man` page for `select()`):

```
void FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
int  FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
void FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
```

A new `fd_set` must be cleared before it is used:

```
FD_ZERO(&my_fd_set);
```

To set a file descriptor in an `fd_set`, do:

```
FD_SET(my_fd, &my_fd_set);
```

Similarly, to remove an fd from an `fd_set`, do:

```
FD_CLR(my_fd, &my_fd_set);
```

To test if a file descriptor is set in an `fd_set` (i.e. to test which descriptors returned ready):

```
if (FD_ISSET(my_fd, &my_fd_set)) {
    // Take action on my_fd
}
```

Comment: This is all correct information, but don't use `fd_set` or `select`. The API is dangerous and inherently causes buffer overflows if the fd limit is set above `FD_SETSIZE` (which is configurable by the invoking user), and is inferior in every way to the modern `poll` API which is also part of the POSIX standard. You should use `poll` in place of select. It's also much easier to use.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE -- thanks for that comment.  I've been reading on the differences between select and poll (not much as it turns out) and I'm happy you said that because it helps me make the choice.